# Spring AOP one method of a class before another

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop

I have an app using Spring Core, Spring MVC, Hibernate. 
There are a lot of DAO classes which get new Hibernate session in every method like this

```
    @Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session session;

private void createSession() {
    session =  sessionFactory.openSession();
}


@Override
public List<User> listUsers() {
    createSession();
    List users;

    users = session.createQuery("from User").list();
    session.close();

    return users;
}
```

I would like to use AOP to execute createSession method before those class methods but can't figure out how to do it.

All I have done was this aspect

```
@Configuration
@Aspect
public class DaoSessionLifeCycle {

    @Before(value = "execution(* ua.com.alistratenko.dao.UserDaoImp.listUsers(..))")
    public void openSession(JoinPoint joinPoint){

        System.out.println("izi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your service method `@Transactional`. Your Dao classes will use the transaction from service. Also read about propagation of transactions.

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk So if I use this annotation I can skip creating/opening new session. In this case what object should I use to work with DB? I mean If i don't need to create session that's mean I dont need instance of this class what else should I use to work with DB?

Comment: There are so many possible reasons why aspects could not work: Spring configuration, aspect code, application code, package names, component scan settings. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just incoherent snippets. Reproducing and analysing your problem makes it so much easier to help you than pure guesswork. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @kriegaex I did not say it does not work. I said I don't know the right way to call one class method before another method of the same class using Aspects.

Comment: So the aspect is triggered and printing "izi" where and when you expect it? And the class of which you only posted the body is actually named `ua.com.alistratenko.dao.UserDaoImp`, as I can only indirectly infer from the pointcut?

Comment: More questions: Why would you want to call `createSession()` from the aspect if it is already called from the method `listUsers()` you are intercepting? Is your goal to remove the call from that method? And are you aware of the fact that the aspect cannot call a private method of another class, but you made `createSession()` private? Would it be okay to make it public? Please answer all questions from both my comments. See, this is exactly why I wanted an MCVE: Your code does not speak for itself and neither does your question explain it.

Comment: @kriegaex I've create that aspect just to check if it works. I want it to open session an close it after all public methods in my UserDAO class. I'd like to remove calling those methods in every method in DAO. I guess making open and close method public is ok if it will help to realize my thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you still did not provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least some more (and more realistic) sample code, I can only speculate and provide a schematic answer.

BTW, I am using AspectJ and not Spring AOP here, but it should work the same way there.

**Dummy classes to make the sample code compile:**

```java
package ua.com.alistratenko.dao;

public class User {
  String name;

  public User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "User [name=" + name + "]";
  }
}
```

```java
package ua.com.alistratenko.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class QueryResult {
  public List<User> list() {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new User("jane"));
    users.add(new User("joe"));
    return users;
  }
}
```

```java
package ua.com.alistratenko.dao;

public class Session {
  public QueryResult createQuery(String string) {
    return new QueryResult();
  }

  public void close() {}
}
```

```java
package ua.com.alistratenko.dao;

public class SessionFactory {
  public Session openSession() {
    return new Session();
  }
}
```

**Application class:**

What did I change?

- In Spring you would use `@Autowired` instead of creating the session factory by yourself. I just did this in order to be able to run my sample code without Spring.
- Added some setters/getters for the aspect to be able to access the session factory and also the session itself
- Removed `createSession()` (code migrated to aspect, see below)
- No more boilerplate clutter in `listUsers()`
- Added main method for demo purposes

```java
package ua.com.alistratenko.dao;

import java.util.List;

public class UserDaoImp {
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory();
  private Session session;

  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() { return sessionFactory; }
  public Session getSession() { return session; }
  public void setSession(Session session) { this.session = session; }

  public List<User> listUsers() {
    return session.createQuery("from User").list();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new UserDaoImp().listUsers();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

In order to do something before + after the intercepted method call, please use `@Around`.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
//import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import ua.com.alistratenko.dao.UserDaoImp;

//@Component
@Aspect
public class DaoSessionLifeCycle {
  @Around("execution(public * listUsers(..)) && target(dao)")
  public Object openSession(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, UserDaoImp dao) throws Throwable {
    try {
      System.out.println("Creating session");
      dao.setSession(dao.getSessionFactory().openSession());
      System.out.println("Calling " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
      return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
    finally {
      try {
        System.out.println("Closing session");
        dao.getSession().close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
Creating session
Calling List ua.com.alistratenko.dao.UserDaoImp.listUsers()
Closing session
```

Now there are several open questions:

- Do you only want to handle this one class or maybe all subclasses of a base class or an implemented interface common to all your DAOs? Then the pointcut would look different.
- Do you only want to intercept method `listUsers()` or maybe also other methods? As you did not show more code, nobody except you can know. The pointcut would also look different depending on your answer.
- Do you really want to do this all manually or maybe follow the other users' advice and use on-board Spring tools in order to manage your transactions? I have no idea about Spring, so I cannot tell you. I was just providing the answer to your question which was aspect-related.

Comment: **Update:** I added dummy classes to make the sample code compile with plain Java SE + AspectJ without Spring container

Comment: Thank You, that's an implementation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Bogdan says, take a look at `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`, it will save you a lot of time. Also, in my opinion, `@Aspect` classes are annotated with `@Component` as opposed to `@Configuration`.

Comment: Yes, a Spring AOP aspect needs to be a `@Component`, whereas a pure AspectJ aspect does not need to.